# Epoxy floor and HDPE foil (Polyethylene) react under pressure?

Tags: floor, plastic, damage, protection, epoxy

I am planning to protect my epoxy floor from scratches with a 0.15mm HD polyethylene foil during some furniture install work.

The epoxy floor has a glossy clear coat and is installed since 1+ years.
The HD polyethylene foil is green UV-treated greenhouse foil.

The thing is, I left a heavy paint bucket overnight on a piece of foil and the next day I noticed that under the foil the epoxy clear coat appears to have developed some non-coloured ridges which seem raised to the touch and are impossible to remove.

Is there any chance that there is some chemical/physical reaction between the foil and the epoxy clear coat or the damage described is just because of the sharp bottom of the heavy paint bucket that laid there?

I did use plastic foil for protection in the past and was not aware of such an issue.
I am trying to avoid any further damage to the floor if I use the same foil during my furniture installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Is there any chance there is some chemical reaction” the answer is absolutely yes there is a chance it may be 1 of 3 I know of ( Fat , slim & none) but there is a chance.
It depends on the type of epoxy flooring paint, I have found multiple customers that were unhappy with 1 part epoxy coatings !
Some that after expensive removal were pleased with 2 part epoxy products.

The 2 part may not be environmentally as good as the 1 part but I have never had a complaint other than myself with the 2 part , after coating a garage, when antifreeze was spilled it was so slippery I could not stand on it!

Ok my backside already had a crack but i busted it several times over. Never found anything that bothered it the coating I meant.

Answer (score 0):

The reaction was not a chemical one, but it seems physical pressure is the only one that damages (they were actually depressions on closer inspection, not raised ridges).
I tested without foil and the heavy paint bucket did the ridges in the same way as with foil if left on the floor overnight.